# Fastest way to extract dictionary of sums in numpy in 1 I/O pass

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dictionary, vectorization

Let's say I have an array like:

```
arr = np.array([[1,20,5],
                [1,20,8],
                [3,10,4],
                [2,30,6],
                [3,10,5]])
```

and I would like to form a dictionary of the sum of the third column for each row that matches each value in the first column, i.e. return `{1: 13, 2: 6, 3: 9}`. To make matters more challenging, there's 1 billion rows in my array and 100k unique elements in the first column.

Approach 1: Naively, I can invoke `np.unique()` then iterate through each item in the unique array with a combination of `np.where()` and `np.sum()` in a one-liner dictionary enclosing a list comprehension. This would be reasonably fast if I have a small number of unique elements, but at 100k unique elements, I will incur a lot of wasted page fetches making 100k I/O passes of the entire array.

Approach 2: I could make a single I/O pass of the last column (because having to hash column 1 at each row will probably be cheaper than the excessive page fetches) too, but I lose the advantage of numpy's C inner loop vectorization here.

Is there a fast way to implement Approach 2 without resorting to a pure Python loop?

Comment: Why not try both and see how it goes?

Comment: @NPE Ooops my bad, I'm thinking of doing approach 2 but I'm only familiar with doing it in a pure Python loop, I know there's `@np.vectorize`, numba and Cython that help to circumvent this, but maybe there's some intelligent way to do this with the numPy library functions alone that someone can point me to...

Comment: Not sure how fast/slow that would be, but you could do it with pandas groupby and sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

numpy approach:

```
u = np.unique(arr[:, 0])
s = ((arr[:, [0]] == u) * arr[:, [2]]).sum(0)

dict(np.stack([u, s]).T)

{1: 13, 2: 6, 3: 9}
```

pandas approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=list('ABC')).groupby('A').C.sum().to_dict()

{1: 13, 2: 6, 3: 9}
```

[image]

Comment: Great suggestions, I ended up using the pandas route that you suggested, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a NumPy based approach using [`np.add.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) -

```
sidx = arr[:,0].argsort()
idx = np.append(0,np.where(np.diff(arr[sidx,0])!=0)[0]+1)
keys = arr[sidx[idx],0]
vals = np.add.reduceat(arr[sidx,2],idx,axis=0)
```

If you would like to get the keys and values in a 2-column array -

```
out = np.column_stack((keys,vals)) # If you
```

Sample run -

```
In [351]: arr
Out[351]: 
array([[ 1, 20,  5],
       [ 1, 20,  8],
       [ 3, 10,  4],
       [ 2, 30,  6],
       [ 3, 10,  5]])

In [352]: out
Out[352]: 
array([[ 1, 13],
       [ 2,  6],
       [ 3,  9]])
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical grouping problem, which the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package solves efficiently and elegantly (if I may say so myself; I am its author)

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.group_by(arr[:, 0]).sum(arr[:, 2])
```

Its a much more lightweight solution than the pandas package, and I think the syntax is cleaner, as there is no need to create a special datastructure just to perform this type of elementary operation. Performance should be identical to the solution posed by Divakar, since it follows the same steps; just with a nice and tested interface on top.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way of doing this is with NumPy is using [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html).  If your unique first column labels are already small contiguous integers you could simply do:

```
cum_sums = np.bincount(arr[:, 0], weights=arr[:, 2])
cum_dict = {index: cum_sum for index, cum_sum in enumerate(cum_sums)
            if cum_sum != 0}
```

where the `cum_sum != 0` is an attempt to skip missing first column labels, which may be grossly wrong if your third column includes negative numbers.

Alternatively you can do things properly and call `np.unique` first and do:

```
uniques, indices = np.unique(arr[:, 0], return_inverse=True)
cum_sums = np.bincount(indices, weights=arr[:, 2])
cum_dict = {index: cum_sum for index, cum_sum in zip(uniques, cum_sums)}
```