# How to sum the second elements of the list if the first elements in the list are matching

Tags: python

Input:

```
[["US", 2], ["UK", 3], ["FR", 4], ["US", 2], ["US", 2], ["UK", 2]]
```

Output:

```
[["US", 6], ["UK", 5], ["FR", 4]]
```

I want to sum the second elements of the list if the first elements in the list are matching. I have tried using the dictionaries and sets but I could not come up with a logic. This could be easily done in Hadoop or Spark as the framework will take of reduce part and we easily sum the list of values. But I am not sure how to do in python. Can somebody please help?

Note: I am looking for optimized solution. Not using many for loops.

## What have been tried:

```
import collections 
l1 = [["US", 2], ["UK", 3], ["FR", 4]] 
l2 = [["US", "us@mail.com"], ["UK", "uk@mail.com"], ["BR", "fr@mail.com"]] 
l1 = dict(l1) 
l2 = dict(l2) 
l1set = set(l1.keys()) 
l2set = set(l2.keys()) 
for i in l1set & l2set: 
    print l2[i]
```

Comment: Please show your work. What have you tried?

Comment: It appears @bernie and I have come up with different solutions. What is the result you're looking for?

Comment: Hello @HaiVu, as I said I couldnot come up with logic. But here is the one I tried for simple list. import collections

l1 = [["US", 2], ["UK", 3], ["FR", 4]]
l2 = [["US", "us@mail.com"], ["UK", "uk@mail.com"], ["BR", "fr@mail.com"]]

l1 = dict(l1)
l2 = dict(l2)

l1set = set(l1.keys())
l2set = set(l2.keys())

for i in l1set & l2set:
    print l2[i]

Comment: @naveench, next time, please update your post not putting code in the comment like this.

Comment: The code you tried has very little to the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections as co
l = [["US", 2], ["UK", 3], ["FR", 4], ["US", 2], ["US", 2], ["UK", 2]]
dd = co.defaultdict(int)
for i in l:
  dd[i[0]] += i[1]
newlist = [list((k,v)) for k,v in dd.items()]
```

Result:

```
>>> newlist
[['FR', 4], ['UK', 5], ['US', 6]]
```

Edit:
If you can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), do the following as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/38497749/42346:

```
import pandas as pd
newlist = [list((k,v)) for k,v in pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['a','b']).groupby('a').b.sum().to_dict().items()]
```

Result:

```
>>> newlist
[['FR', 4], ['US', 6], ['UK', 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a list comprehension:

```
myNewList = [i for i in listOne if i in listTwo]
```

Here's an example:

```
listOne = [2, 4, 5, 7]
listTwo = [2, 3, 5, 6]

print ([i for i in listOne if i in listTwo])
# prints [2, 5]
```

Here's what I got when I ran it with both of your lists:

```
$ python test.py
[['FR', 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First if you don't know how to do it you don't need optimization but  I'll give myself a challenge of 5 seconds to answer your question :)

```
from collections import defaultdict
b=defaultdict(int)
a=[["US", 2], ["UK", 3], ["FR", 4], ["US", 2], ["US", 2], ["UK", 2]]
for i in a: b[i[0]]+=i[1]

#now the way you access your sum is 
print b['UK'] #prints 5

#if you specificlly need that format
output = [[n,b[n]] for n in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `itertools.groupby`, `reduce` and list comprehensions, like so:

```
a = [["US", 2], ["UK", 3], ["FR", 4], ["US", 2], ["US", 2], ["UK", 2]]
a.sort()
b = []
for k, g in groupby(a, lambda x: x[0]):
    b.append([k, reduce(lambda p, c: p + c, [y[1] for y in g])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Group them by name, sum the numbers for each group:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

my_list = [["US", 2], ["UK", 3], ["FR", 4], ["US", 2], ["US", 2], ["UK", 2]]

summary_list = []

for name, group in groupby(sorted(my_list), key=itemgetter(0)): 
   summary_list.append([name, sum(item[1] for item in group)])

print(summary_list)
```

Output:

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

[['FR', 4], ['UK', 5], ['US', 6]]
```

Try it online: https://repl.it/Ceh6/1

Answer (score 0):

Starting with this:

```
  ll =[["US", 2], ["UK", 3], ["FR", 4], ["US", 2], ["US", 2], ["UK", 2]]
```

Try this:

```
 dd = {k:0 for k in dict(ll).keys()}
 for x in ll: dd[x[0]] += x[1]
 dd
 {'FR': 4, 'UK': 5, 'US': 6}

 [[k,v] for k,v in  dd.iteritems()]

 [['FR', 4], ['US', 6], ['UK', 5]]
```